# pop index out of range in while

Tags: python, list

I'm making Tic tac toe, and I want to make the `Computer` variable never choose what the `Player` input chose.

```
from ast import If

import random

from re import X

wordlist = [' ',' ',' '], [' ',' ', ' '], [' ',' ',' ']

wordlist2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

def Game():
    for element in wordlist:
        print(element)
        
while True:
    
    Player = input()
    
    Computer = random.choice(wordlist2)
    
    #Player
    if Player == '1':
        wordlist[0][0] = 'x'
        if Player == '1':
            wordlist2.pop(0)
        
    if Player == '2':
        wordlist[0][1] = 'x'
        if Player == '2':
            wordlist2.pop(1)
        
    if Player == '3':
        wordlist[0][2] = 'x'
        if Player == '3':
            wordlist2.pop(2)

        
    if Player == '4':
        wordlist[1][0] = 'x'
        if Player == '4':
            wordlist2.pop(3)
        
    if Player == '5':
        wordlist[1][1] = 'x'
        if Player == '5':
            wordlist2.pop(4)
        
    if Player == '6':
        wordlist[1][2] = 'x'
        if Player == '6':
            wordlist2.pop(5)
        
    if Player == '7':
        wordlist[2][0] = 'x'
        if Player == '7':
            wordlist2.pop(6)
        
    if Player == '8':
        wordlist[2][1] = 'x'
        if Player == '8':
            wordlist2.pop(7)
        
    if Player == '9':
        wordlist[2][2] = 'x'
        if Player == '9':
            wordlist2.pop(8)
        
    #Computer
    
    if Computer == '1':
        wordlist[0][0] = 'o'
        
    if Computer == '2':
        wordlist[0][1] = 'o'
        
    if Computer == '3':
        wordlist[0][2] = 'o'
        
    if Computer == '4':
        wordlist[1][0] = 'o'
        
    if Computer == '5':
        wordlist[1][1] = 'o'
        
    if Computer == '6':
        wordlist[1][2] = 'o'
        
    if Computer == '7':
        wordlist[2][0] = 'o'
        
    if Computer == '8':
        wordlist[2][1] = 'o'
        
    if Computer == '9':
        wordlist[2][2] = 'o'
        
    Game()
```

### The Error

> Exception has occurred: IndexError pop index out of range

Comment: I advice you to start accept given you answers...

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your question, I see 3 problems...

1. Pop method uses the index and that will change every time you remove an element, probably easier to use [remove](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method instead, just mind that it uses the values not the indexes.
2. Move the computer selection after all the players conditions (IFs) or the player and computer might end up with the same number.
3. You are just removing the player numbers, remove the numbers the computer plays too.

Let me suggest a couple of extra things:

1. All conditions are IFs, this will cause problems, first player condition should be IF and then use [ELIF](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html), same thing for the computer.
2. This game will never have a winner, it will run until no more numbers available and then fail with a horrible traceback. Add some code to find lines and declare a winner or to say it is a tie if there are no more numbers to pick.
3. Based on my experience it might be easier to use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for this kind of project

Hope this helps, you are almost there!

Comment: Thankyu very much for helping me sir, all i need now is break statements, thanks again :)